# Get new questions, comments, tag changes, edits, new answers on all questions with a tag in RSS

Tags: feature-request, feed

Is it possible to get **all changes** to questions filtered by **tag** (comments, edits, answers, tag changes, etc.) in **one RSS feed** for Stack Exchange sites?

For example all changes to questions with tag 'Jira'.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Stack2RSS](http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/) (an application I wrote), such a feed can indeed be constructed.

Given the question ID, you can keep track of events that occur using the following URL template:

> `http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/` **`{site}`** `/questions/` **`{question_id}`** `/timeline`

Example: http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/askubuntu.com/questions/5/timeline

Comment: I do not know question id. I would like to get all questions filtered by a tag. Sorry the question does not specify it anymore, someone decided to edit it and seems like some info went missing. Added example in the question.

Comment: Hmmm... my app will allow you to specify multiple question IDs. But it won't automatically fetch those IDs for you.